# Some notifications are clickable some are not

Tags: android, notifications

I am getting multiple Local notifications of range 1-10..

I am getting getting notifications with its content and title.. but when i click the notification only first notification open and when i click rest the notification disappear and it show activity but the content remain the same that one of first notification.. Here is my code

on clicking notification i applied this code

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Message_activity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("randomStr", randomStr);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pndng = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and getting like this in message activity

```
  String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("randomStr");
        Log.e("randomStrrandomStr", getIntent().getStringExtra("randomStr"));
        fullmsg.setText(message);
```

Please suggest something Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guest you used same id for each time you notify a notification by call `notify` method of `NotificationManager`. So try to use different id for each time you call `notify`.